# On submitting to this post request, the main code is not getting executed, it is always reaching the catch block why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, asynchronous

I'm not properly handling async operation. I'm trying to write values  that are received on app.post('/receiver') route, to an excel file. I'm using exceljs npm package. When I try this as a separate one its perfectly working, but when call this exceljs function from app.post its not working.

I wanna write/ read an excel file when My client sends a post request to the route /receive. But here the code is always reaching the catch block, I even tried removing this

```
app.post('/receiver',function(req, res){
   var data = [req.body.deviceid, req.body.purposeofvisit, req.body.componentsused,req.body.rectification,req.body.hoursspent,req.body.completed, req.body.reason]
   console.log(data);
   workBook.xlsx.readFile('/routes/book.xlsx').then(function() {
      var worksheet = workBook.getWorksheet(1);
      var row = worksheet.getRow(7);
      row.getCell(8).value = "AF22e-3852"; 
      row.commit();
      workBook.xlsx.writeFile('/routes/book.xlsx');
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/in.html'));
   }).catch(function(){
      console.log('Catch reached')
   });
});
```

My current Output:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vRTO.png)
Require Output:

Client request: /receiver (posts data)
Server on reception: Writes these values to an excel file (I'm using exceljs package)

Comment: instead of display string error, display error itself.

`.catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
   })`

Comment: Have you verified that `workBook.xlsx.readFile('/routes/book.xlsx')` is actually working? As Radonirina says, log out the caught exception to see the actual error.

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot It was just a File Not Found Error. OMG! I forgot to create that file. Thanks a lot!